# 2D segment tree update/modification step complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am having trouble understanding the complexity of the "Modification query" in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-dimensional-segment-tree-sub-matrix-sum/. It states at the bottom of the article that the complexity is O(2 * n * log n * log m). Why is it not just O(log n * log m)? Where did the extra linear term n come from?

Answer (score 2):

Check their update implementation

```py
def update(pos, low, high, x, y, val): 
  
    if (low == high) : 
        finalUpdate(1, 1, 4, x, val, pos) 
      
    else : 
        mid = (low + high) // 2
  
        if (low <= y and y <= mid) : 
            update(2 * pos, low, mid, x, y, val) 
  
        else : 
            update(2 * pos + 1, mid + 1,  
                       high, x, y, val) 
  
        for i in range(1, size): 
            fin_seg[pos][i] = (fin_seg[2 * pos][i] +
                               fin_seg[2 * pos + 1][i])
```

Notice that at the end of the combination step it is iterating over all the columns of the array and updating all the items of the the corresponding tree. This is where the `n` comes from. But I would say that the complexity is O(n * log(m) + log(n)`, because final update is called only once and does only` log(n)` changes

#### An implementation without the `n` factor

An implementation that only recalculates the nodes that depends on the changed element would have complexity `O(log(n)*log(m))`. This can be achieved by keeping track of the changed elements in the `finalUpdate`.

```py
def finalUpdate(pos, low, high, x, val, node): 
    if (low == high) : 
        fin_seg[node][pos] = val 
        return [pos]
    else : 
        mid = (low + high) // 2
  
        if (low <= x and x <= mid) : 
            changes = finalUpdate(2 * pos, low, mid,  
                            x, val, node) 
          
        else : 
            changes = finalUpdate(2 * pos + 1, mid + 1,  
                            high, x, val, node) 
  
        changes.append(pos);
        fin_seg[node][pos] = (fin_seg[node][2 * pos] + 
                              fin_seg[node][2 * pos + 1]) 
        return changes
```

The `finalUpdate` is a binary search and thus will be called `log(m)` recursion, each call changes one element, so changes will be log(m).

```
def update(pos, low, high, x, y, val): 
  
    if (low == high) : 
        changes = finalUpdate(1, 1, 4, x, val, pos) 
      
    else : 
        mid = (low + high) // 2
  
        if (low <= y and y <= mid) : 
            changes = update(2 * pos, low, mid, x, y, val) 
  
        else : 
            changes = update(2 * pos + 1, mid + 1,  
                       high, x, y, val) 
  
        for i in changes: 
            fin_seg[pos][i] = (fin_seg[2 * pos][i] +
                               fin_seg[2 * pos + 1][i]) 
    return changes;
```

Update makes a binary search and will be called `log(n)` times, each call will re calculate `log(m)` nodes.

Comment: Ahh I didn't see the for loop. Yeah I think the loop is pointless. Though with the loop, I think the complexity should be O(n log m + log n) = O(n log m)

Comment: Ah you are right, I must have made confusions with `m`, `n`.

Comment: @user5965026 does this post answer your question? If not, what is it that is missing here?